# How to align left and full-height side nav menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, menu

I'm trying to build a sidenavigation menu for the tablet / mobile part of my website. What I can't do is get a left-alignment of the screen, an overlay and full-height. I am new and looking to learn, can someone help me please? I appreciate any response, thanks.

This is the approximate result that I would like to achieve: https://codepen.io/bousahla-mounir/pen/jOypjed I am not interested in aesthetics, but rather I want to get the full-screen side container with the elements inside.

This is what I did for sidenav: In the example below it is aligned to the left, but in my website it is not because it is inside a column. It then aligns to the left of that column instead of the furthest part of the screen.

```js
var menu = document.querySelector(".mob_menu_button");
function mobile_menu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mts_mobile_menu");
  if (!x.classList.contains("side_show")) {
    x.classList.add ("side_show");
    menu.innerHTML = '<span>Menu Open</span>';
 
    
  } else { 
    x.classList.add("side_hide");
    menu.innerHTML = '<span>Menu Closed</span>';

    setTimeout(function(){
     x.classList.remove("side_show");
     x.classList.remove("side_hide");  
    },500)
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*Items menu*/

.user_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/*Menu header info*/

.display.name {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #303238;
}

.display.mail {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #3d5afe;
}

hr.solid {
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}


/*Text Link css*/

.user_menu.item>a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #75777D;
}

.user_menu.item:hover>a {
  color: #2E323A;
}


/*Icon Button Toggle Menu*/

.mob_menu_button {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: #fbfbfb !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}

.icn_button {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.icn_button:before {
  margin: 0;
}

.icn_button:after {
  margin: 0;
}


/*Icon Items Menu*/
.icn_menu:before,
.icon_menu:after {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 16px
}

.icn_menu {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}


/* User Menu For header website */
.mts_menu_container {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; 
}

.mts_sidenav_box {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mts_sidenav_content {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 260px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  animation: animateFromLeft .6s
}

@keyframes animateFromLeft {
  from {
    left: -500px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animateToLeft {
  from {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    left: -500px;
    opacity: 0
  }
}

.side_show {
  display: block !important;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mts_sidenav_content.side_hide {
  animation: animateToLeft .6s
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mobile_menu()" class="mob_menu_button">
     Menu
</button>

<div class="mts_mob_container">
  <div class="mts_sidenav_box">
      
   <div id="mts_mobile_menu" class="mts_sidenav_content">
       
    <div class="user_menu header">
        <span class="display name">Ciao [display_name]</span>
        <span class="display mail">[display_email]</span>
    </div>   
      
     <hr class="solid">  
     
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="/account">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-user"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
     <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="ordini">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-basket-shopping"></i>
         <span class="link_text">I miei ordini</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="libreria">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-cloud-arrow-down"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Downloads</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="impostazioni">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-gear"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Impostazioni</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_menu item">
        <a href="wp-login.php?action=logout">
         <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>
         <span class="link_text">Logout</span>
        </a>
    </div>
   </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were most of the way there but there's a few things you missed in your attempt:

You have some classes you aren't using and are blank and were causing layout issues, so I took them out. If you need them you can add them back in but they weren't doing anything when I ran your code except causing issues.

You can globally set your styles to have no margin, padding, and box-sizing: border-box from the get-go and then adjust down your CSS as needed but by declaring it at the start you're not letting the browser make a decision for you (nor should you; you're the programmer! ;) ).

The button just needs to be sized and positioned absolutely, just like the example you provided. To have the menu take up the entirety of the viewport height, use the `100vh` unit. See: https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/

See if this gets you where you want to go and we can troubleshoot further as necessary. :)

```js
var menu = document.querySelector(".mob_menu_button");

function mobile_menu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mts_mobile_menu");
  if (!x.classList.contains("side_show")) {
    x.classList.add("side_show");
    menu.innerHTML = '<span>Icon</span>';


  } else {
    x.classList.add("side_hide");
    menu.innerHTML = '<span>Icon</span>';

    setTimeout(function() {
      x.classList.remove("side_show");
      x.classList.remove("side_hide");
    }, 500)
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*Items menu*/

.user_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/*Menu header info*/

.display.name {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #303238;
}

.display.mail {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #3d5afe;
}

hr.solid {
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}


/*Text Link css*/

.user_menu.item>a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #75777D;
}

.user_menu.item:hover>a {
  color: #2E323A;
}


/*Icon Button Toggle Menu*/

.mob_menu_button {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background: #fbfbfb !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}

.icn_button {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.icn_button:before {
  margin: 0;
}

.icn_button:after {
  margin: 0;
}


/*Icon Items Menu*/

.icn_menu:before,
.icon_menu:after {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 16px
}

.icn_menu {
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
}


/* User Menu For header website */

.mts_menu_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.mts_sidenav_box {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 17px;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mts_sidenav_content {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 280px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  animation: animateFromLeft .6s
}

@keyframes animateFromLeft {
  from {
    left: -500px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animateToLeft {
  from {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    left: -500px;
    opacity: 0
  }
}

.side_show {
  display: block !important;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mts_sidenav_content.side_hide {
  animation: animateToLeft .6s
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mobile_menu()" class="mob_menu_button">
     <span>Icon</span>
</button>

<div class="mts_menu_container">
  <div id="mts_mobile_menu" class="mts_sidenav_content">

    <div class="user_menu header">
      <span class="display name">Ciao [display_name]</span>
      <span class="display mail">[display_email]</span>
    </div>

    <hr class="solid">

    <div class="user_menu item">
      <a href="/account">
        <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-user">1</i>
        <span class="link_text">Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="user_menu item">
      <a href="ordini">
        <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-basket-shopping">2</i>
        <span class="link_text">I miei ordini</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="user_menu item">
      <a href="libreria">
        <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-cloud-arrow-down">3</i>
        <span class="link_text">Downloads</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="user_menu item">
      <a href="impostazioni">
        <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-gear">4</i>
        <span class="link_text">Impostazioni</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="user_menu item">
      <a href="wp-login.php?action=logout">
        <i class="icn_menu fa-regular fa-arrow-right-from-bracket">5</i>
        <span class="link_text">Logout</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your suggestion was very helpful to me. It wasn't the solution for me, but it helped me solve the problem. I update the post with the code that is working for me.

Ps: the key I need to keep it full-width because I need it aesthetically and it is present within a section of elementor.

Comment: @Snorlax sounds good! If you could mark this as answered I’d appreciate it and if you need any additional assistance with this you can ping me at AStombaugh :)

Comment: Thank you for your support. Would you like to help me here too? I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, I see your question. When I get home I'll take a look at it if someone doesn't beat me to it :)

Comment: I forgot the link in the previous comment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72239855/how-to-close-sidenav-menu-when-click-out-of-container-div